# jQuery same function for multiple objects

Tags: jquery

I have two tab navigations and I like to run them side by side.
The first one works well for itself, but when I duplicate it, I run into problems.

How do I make this tab navigations work side by side?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // configurator tabs
  $('.tab-link').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    var tab_id_input = $(this).children("input");

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('ul.tabs li input').prop('checked', false).removeAttr('checked');
    $('.variant--group').removeClass('current');

    $("." + tab_id).addClass('current');
    $(tab_id_input).prop('checked', true).attr('checked', 'checked');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');

    $('.variant--group.current').prevAll().removeClass('slide-left slide-right').addClass('slide-left');
    $('.variant--group.current').nextAll().removeClass('slide-left slide-right').addClass('slide-right');
  })

  // arrow navigation
  $('#previous').click(function() {
    $('.variant--group.current').prevAll().removeClass('slide-left slide-right').addClass('slide-left');
    if ($('ul.tabs li.current').prev().length != 0) {
      $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current').click();
    }
  })

  $('#next').click(function() {
    $('.variant--group.current').nextAll().removeClass('slide-left slide-right').addClass('slide-right');
    if ($('ul.tabs li.current').next().length != 0) {
      $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current').click();
    }
  })


  $('#resp-button').click(function() {
    $('.product--detail-upper').addClass("show");
    $('body').addClass("fixed");
  })

  $('.product--detail-upper').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target !== this)
      return;
    $('.product--detail-upper').removeClass("show");
    $('body').removeClass("fixed");
  });

  // keyboard navigation
  $("body").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
      $('.variant--group.current').prevAll().removeClass('slide-left slide-right').addClass('slide-left');
      if ($('ul.tabs li.current').prev().length != 0) {
        $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').prev().addClass('current').click();
      }
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) { // right
      $('.variant--group.current').nextAll().removeClass('slide-left slide-right').addClass('slide-right');
      if ($('ul.tabs li.current').next().length != 0) {
        $('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current').next().addClass('current').click();
      }
    }
  });


});
```

```css
.body {
  background: #111;
}

.tabscontain {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
.tabs li {
  background: #f6f7f9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tabs li.current {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ffffff;
  color: #09c;
}
.arrows {
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
  top: -130px;
}
.arrow {
  background: #30373b;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow:active {
  background: #222222;
}
.variant--group {
  display: none;
  min-height: 190px;
  padding: 60px 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.variant--group.current {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.variant--group.slide-left.current {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100px);
  animation: slide-left 0.4s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-left {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-left {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes slide-left {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-left {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.variant--group.slide-right.current {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100px);
  animation: slide-right 0.4s ease forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide-right {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-right {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes slide-right {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes slide-right {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- First Tab -->
<div class="custom-slide">

  <div class="arrows slide-left">
    <div id="previous" class="arrow">Zurück</div>
    <div id="next" class="arrow">Weiter</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabscontain slide-left">
    <ul class="tabs">

      <li class="tab-link 1 current" data-tab="1">option 1</li>
      <li class="tab-link 2" data-tab="2">option 2</li>
      <li class="tab-link 3" data-tab="3">option 3</li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="variant--group slide-left current" id="1">
    <div class="descript">
      <h2>option 1</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="variant--group slide-left current" id="2">
    <div class="descript">
      <h2>option 2</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="variant--group slide-left current" id="3">
    <div class="descript">
      <h2>option 3</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>



<!-- Second Tab -->
<div class="custom-slide">

  <div class="arrows slide-left">
    <div id="previous" class="arrow">Zurück</div>
    <div id="next" class="arrow">Weiter</div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabscontain slide-left">
    <ul class="tabs">

      <li class="tab-link 4 current" data-tab="4">option 3</li>
      <li class="tab-link 5" data-tab="5">option 4</li>
      <li class="tab-link 6" data-tab="6">option 5</li>

    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="variant--group slide-left current" id="4">
    <div class="descript">
      <h2>option 4</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="variant--group slide-left current" id="5">
    <div class="descript">
      <h2>option 5</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="variant--group slide-left current" id="6">
    <div class="descript">
      <h2>option 6</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want two independent sliders, you'll need to address the following issues:

1. The range of the second slider is incorrect
2. The content of each tab should be initially hidden
3. Key events will inevitably affect both sliders

But the main problem is that your code needs a reference for each of the sliders, in order to manage them independently. You can use the *custom-slide* class as a wrapper and animate only its children :

```
var slide = $(this).closest('.custom-slide');
```

I trimmed your code and created a small example :

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r_costa/dc1k4s9v/)